# Publishing presentations in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, media

I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to publish a presentation inside WordPress.

I do not want to attach a PPT file or embed a Flash plugin for that, I'm looking for a HTML solution.

I would be preferable to be able to use PowerPoint to create the presentation but this is not a hard requirement, more important is to output a nice presentation for the users, one with auto-play.

Comment: Another solution is to use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-document-embedder/ (This is what I use)

Comment: You can also try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/speakerdeck-embed/. Just paste your speakerdeck slides URL into your page or post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this problem before with both PPT files and PDF documents.  The solution, actually, was quite simple ...

There's a plug-in called [PDF and PPT Viewer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdf-and-ppt-viewer/) that will uses Google Docs to render your presentation inside the page.  Each slide/page is rendered as a image using Google's API rather than Flash or a native file viewer.

I'm using this extensively on my portfolio to show PDF files without requiring a file download or browser plug-in.  Here's a specific, live example of a press release I did in January: http://work.eamann.com/2010/02/publicity-release/.

Note how the plug-in embeds the Google viewer in an iFrame on the page.  The file itself is hosted on my own site (I used the WordPress media gallery uploader).

**Important:** The plug-in download page claims the system is only tested through WP 2.8.4, however the site I've referenced above is using 3.0.1 ... it *is* compatible with the latest release of WordPress, the author just hasn't updated the documentation yet!

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost thinking this question is out of scope, being more a *"How do I get a PowerPoint presentation displayed on the web"* and less of a WordPress question. But I'll go ahead and make a few suggestions:

### Use HTML Slidy or S5?

You can integrate [**HTML Slidy**](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/) or [**S5**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/s5-intro.html) into WordPress using a [shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/how-do-i-add-my-own-custom-shortcodes). Regarding conversation from PPT to (X)HTML, here are references:

- [**PowerPoint to HTML**](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=46) (also *"[Showing off S5](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/41732)"*)
- [**PPT2HTML**](http://www.pptools.com/ppt2html/index.html)

### Use SlideShare?

Alternately you can consider using [**SlideShare**](http://www.slideshare.net/) which has the added benefit of making your slides available in the SlideShare community (assuming broader exposure is a benefit.) Here's a plugin to help:

- [**SlideShare Plugin for WordPress**](http://yoast.com/wordpress/slideshare/)

#### Also See:

- [**PowerPoint & Friends: Accessible Slides On The Web**](http://staff.washington.edu/tft/talks/powerpoint/s5.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am using GroupDocs Viewer Plugin for WordPress and it is working like a charm for me, I am getting viewing and optional downloading of files, such as DOC, DOCX, PDF, XLS, XLSX, PPT, PPTX and other formats. There is no need of additional Flash or PDF browser plugins.

http://groupdocs.com/blog/groupdocs-viewer/archive/2012/07/24/announcing-groupdocs-viewer-plugin-for-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Embed button on the presentation and then copy and paste the 'shortcode for WordPress.com blogs as shown below[image: Generating embed code for Slideshare for Wordpress]